# MonoMac - linker breaks app

Tags: c#, .net, macos, mono, monomac

If I build my app with "Link SDK only" for a release build (for beta testing on machines without Mono), it no longer starts up--it seems to crash immediately.

Here is the crash if I run my app command line:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationHost.
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, Boolean nonPublic) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationSystem.Init (System.Type typeConfigHost, System.Object[] hostInitParams) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.InternalConfigurationFactory.Create (System.Type typeConfigHost, System.Object[] hostInitConfigurationParams) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfigurationInternal (ConfigurationUserLevel userLevel, System.Reflection.Assembly calling_assembly, System.String exePath) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.get_Configuration () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.System.Configuration.Internal.IInternalConfigSystem.GetSection (System.String configKey) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.GetConfig (System.String sectionName) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Any way to add the appropriate `[Preserve]` attribute here? Or maybe force the linker to keep this class?

Some more info:

- My app is a [MonoGame](http://monogame.net) game, called [Draw a Stickman: EPIC](http://epic.drawastickman.com)
- It runs just fine if I don't link any assemblies, but my app is 10MB bigger
- Originally I had gotten some errors from the linker with Tao.Sdl.dll, but I referenced it in my main project, which fixed it.
- I'm targeting 10.6 and higher

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A major difference for **MMP** (MonoMac Packer), when compared to MonoTouch's `mtouch`, is that MonoMac uses the full .NET framework. That makes linking application a lot more complex.

Why ? mostly because of `System.Configuration` (it's an assembly but it's also a namespace in several other assemblies). It uses reflection and `.config` files to set itself up - and the linker can't know (since it can change between execution) exactly what's needed for your application.

MMP *tries* to cover the most common cases (e.g. System.Net) but it does not, currently, handle every case where System.Configuration is used inside the BCL.

Now to fix that... **you** need to tell the linker to include everything your application will need at runtime. E.g.

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: 
An exception was thrown by the type initializer for System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer 
---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system. 
---> System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationHost.
```

That means your application is using (even if indirectly) `System.Configuration.ExeConfigurationHost` and the linker could not detect it (it's used thru reflection).

From there you need to [build an XML file](http://spouliot.wordpress.com/2012/04/27/linker-versus-customization/) to *teach* the linker about those required types (there will be others, likely many others). That XML file is then fed back to MMP (--xml=FILE) so the linker won't try to remove those types/methods from your linked application.

Alternatives are **not linking** or not linking some assemblies (e.g. `--linkskip=System`). YMMV.

**UPDATE:** The new [Xamarin.Mac](http://xamarin.com/mac), a superset of MonoMac, contains an enhanced version of the linker that will solve this exception (but maybe not all the other ones, please fill bug report for them).

Comment: poupou, great info. So are the XML files just a list of namespaces/types to skip linking on? Your blog post is a bit vague on what to put in the XML file. I'll play around with it in the mean time.

Comment: @jonathanpeppers My blog post links to some (real) XML files used by `monolinker` -> https://github.com/mono/mono/tree/master/mcs/tools/linker/Descriptors

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

- Is anything printed in the Console app?
- Try executing MyApp.app/Contents/MacOS/(binary) from a terminal, this should print something to the terminal at least.

Comment: Thanks that got me the error. Any ideas on the stack trace above?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because mmp (the MonoMac packager built into MonoDevelop) strips out too much from the framework.  Especially when using XML.

I found you have to pass these additional arguments to mmp for XML to work:

```
--linkskip=System.Net --linkskip=System --linkskip=System.Configuration --linkskip=mscorlib
```

Unfortunately, the mmp arguments in the project config in monodevelop are not functional (do no save).  I have reported these bugs and were fixed but don't seem like they will be available until a later version for some reason.

For now, you can run mmp from the command line. The build output shows the current command so you can use that but add the arguments above.

It is still quite worth while to do this, it took my app from 20mb down to 10mb even without linking those libraries.